# Can you explain how the methods of the class are called?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

conv.h

```
class Base 
{
public:
    void foo();
};

class Derived: public Base 
{
public:
    void bar();
};

class A {};
class B 
{
public:
    void koko();
};
```

conv.cpp

```
void Base::foo()
{
    cout<<"stamm";
}

void Derived::bar()
{
    cout<<"bar shoudn't work"<<endl;
}
void B::koko()
{
    cout<<"koko shoudn't work"<<endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "conv.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{   
    Base * a = new Base;
    Derived * b = static_cast<Derived*>(a);
    b->bar();

    Derived * c = reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(a);
    c->bar();

    A* s1 = new A;
    B* s2 = reinterpret_cast<B*>(s1);
    s2->koko();
}
```

output:

```
bar shoudn't work
bar shoudn't work
koko shoudn't work
```

How come the method bar is succeeded to be called in run time despite that I have created a Base class not derived?? it works even with two types of conversions (static and reinterpret cast).

same question as above but with unrelated classes (A & B) ??

Comment: Its not recommended to override the compiler checks using `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` to run such unsafe conversions unless we know that conversion would work.

Comment: Bad things happen when you lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working (read: "compiling and not crashing") 'cause you never use the `this` pointer in your nominally "member" functions.  If you tried to print out a member variable, for example, you'd get the garbage output or crashes you expect - but these functions as they are now don't depend on anything in the classes they're supposedly part of.  `this` could even be `NULL` for all they care.

Comment: I would say "It appears to work". Its not actually working. Undefined behavior may look like it works on one platform and fall completely on its face on anther platform. The OP is just getting lucky on this platform.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Fair enough.  I think OP knows how bad the code is, though; I read the question more as "Look at this mess - how come the C++ gods don't come down and smite me with a segfault for even attempting it?"

Answer (score 6):

Undefined behaviour can do anything, including appear to work.

Comment: okay I know that it is undefined behaviour but what"s going behind it? how come it works?

Comment: @user1669812: You seem to have missed the important bit; *"Undefined behaviour can do anything, **including appear to work.**"*.  Undefined behavior doesn't mean "will crash" or something similar.  That would be defined behavior.  Undefined behavior means *anything* can happen.  Not sure how to make that any more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows a `Derived` can use member functions `foo()` and `bar()` and knows where to find them.  After you did your "tricks", you had pointers to `Derived`.

The fact that they were pointers of type `Derived` -- regardless of what *data* was associated with those pointers -- allowed them to call the functions `foo()` and `kook()` associated with Derived.

As has been mentioned, if you had actually used the data at the pointers (i.e. read or wrote data members relative to `this` belonging to the Derived class (which you don't have in this case), you would have been access memory that didn't belong to your objects.